# Running Google Test with buggy test setup leads to unexpected result

Tags: c++, visual-studio, googletest

I am using Google Test in conjunction with Visual Studio 2019. If everything is working, the tests show up in the Test Explorer with the option to run after compiling.

However, if there is ANY problem with the setup for ANY test, everything can compile without errors but no tests are discoverable. For example, if in the code file I have a class

```
class Object {
public:
    int member;

}
```

and then in the test file I have

```
TEST(package, tn) {
Object obj;

cout << obj.member << endl;

}
```

This will compile without problems but suddenly no tests with be discoverable, and I'll have absolutely no idea what went wrong. Is there a way around this problem?